# How to properly intercept click on close button from tabview page?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo, tabview

I have a standard instance of `qx.ui.tabview.TabView` with some pages which have their close button enabled. I would like to intercept a click on the close button to display a confirmation dialog but I can't figure out how to do it the qooxdoo way.

As a workaround I found that I can overwrite `tabview._onPageClose()` but since I am not subclassing TabView this seems to be a hack.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Subclassing is the way to go because overriding the method without subclassing is a hack as you already said.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but you could also attach an event handler to the tab page's close event, and try to cancel propagation in the bubbling phase, showing your confirmation instead. Then, after OK in the confirmation dialog, just close the tab programmatically.

Also, the tabview page exposes its child controls, and the TabButton exposes its child controls - the close-button among them. You could try adding a listener directly to that button, in which you cancel propagation (Event.stop()), and display your confirmation.